# Combining array to get an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, hash

I have three arrays that need to be stored together for future use. Each array is related to each other, and every array element per position is meant to be matched together. The arrays elements orders will always be correct, but beyond that, there is no easy way to discern the correct order once lost.

How can I combine these arrays together without losing their original order?

I am assuming that an array of hashes is the best way to go, but, please let me know if I'm wrong in that assumption.

Example Arrays:

```
my @numbers = (5,2,7,32,9);
my @letters = qw(z b t t c);
my @words   = qw(tiny book lawn very dance);
```

Example end result.

```
my @combined_arrays = (
       {
           'number' => '5',
           'letter' => 'z',
           'word'   => 'tiny',
       },
       {
           'number' => '2',
           'letter' => 'b',
           'word'   => 'book',
       },
       {
           'number' => '7',
           'letter' => 't',
           'word'   => 'lawn',
       },
       {
           'number' => '32',
           'letter' => 't',
           'word'   => 'very',
       },
       {
           'number' => '9',
           'letter' => 'c',
           'word'   => 'dance',
       },
);
```

Comment: Why not use an array of arrays: `my @combined_arrays = (\@numbers, \@letters, \@words )` ? or `my @combined_arrays = ([@numbers], [@letters], [@words] )` if you need to make a copy...

Comment: Other than the shown hashes it may also be an array-of-arrays as `([5,'z','tiny'], ...)`, if you want to group them by position.  For how to create either see [this recent page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50960273/4653379) (near duplicate).

Comment: I should have mentioned I wanted to pour this into a db at some point. I was thinking that the array of hashes would be easier to iterate over.

Comment: @user: There seems to be no reason to use hashes. If you know that the items are always in the order `number`, `letter`, `word` then there is no confusion. I also recommend an array of arrays for simplicity and economy of space. (Using hashes, you would be storing many many copies of the three strings `'number'`, `'letter'`, and `'word'`)

Comment: I don't have a problem with an array of arrays, assuming I understand the proper way to iterate through them.  I originally tried the loop push @hoffmeister suggested, but had trouble breaking out of it and not creating duplicates, but his map solution doesn't appear to make copies.

Comment: @user: I don't see how you could create duplicates unless there are duplicate sets of three in your data that you want to remove. Iterating through an array of arrays should be trivial, and simpler than if you had used hashes. You'll need to give an example of what you want to do, probably in a new question.

Comment: Oh, no the problem was solved for me.  @hoffmeister's answer did the trick.

Comment: @user: Sure, but that answer shows how to build an array of hashes, which as I've said is unnecessary, very wasteful, and long-winded to process. I'm trying to address your "trouble breaking out of [the loop] and not creating duplicates". You should learn how to do this properly sooner rather than later, and not just accept the first example that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
my @combined_arrays = map { "number" => $numbers[$_] , "letter" => $letters[$_] , "word" => $words[$_] } , 0..@letters-1;
```

Comment: I very much, made this more complicated than it needed to be.  Thanks, that does it. :)

Comment: NP, map is really handy for one liners where you need to iterate though a list. You could have also done this using a for loop and push each entry onto the array. However, this would take an extra line ;-)

Comment: `@letters-1` == `$#letters` :)

Answer (score 3):

I realise you've already accepted an answer, but I thought I'd just throw out a more concise option that relies on some modules.

I'm using `zip` (aka `mesh`, from either [`List::SomeUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::SomeUtils) or [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils)) and `zip_by` (from [`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy)), but I'm importing both of them via [`List::AllUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::AllUtils).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::AllUtils qw( zip zip_by );

my @numbers = (5,2,7,32,9);
my @letters = qw(z b t t c);
my @words   = qw(tiny book lawn very dance);
my @keys    = qw(number letter word);

my @combined = zip_by { +{ zip @keys, @_ } } \@numbers, \@letters, \@words;
```

It's potentially more readable, but only if you're familiar with what `zip` and `zip_by` do. At the very least, it fits inside 80 characters.

**Update**
I originally had `\%{{ zip @keys, @_ }}` inside the `zip_by`. This was to force it to interpret my curlies as a hash-ref. Then I remembered that `+{}` is a prettier way to disambiguate.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.